# connect Qt and Matlab via ActiveX

Tags: matlab, qt, com, activeqt, qaxobject

I have connected Qt to Matlab via ActiveX. So, now I can execute scripts which is written in Qt GUI. However I have faced to problems. How do I know that user closed Matlab manually by clicking close button? Sometimes I send scripts with optimisation functions and it may perform in Matlab for upto 10 minutes. How do I know that script is performed and Matlab is ready for another command? I have called `generateDocumentation` function of `QAxObject` class. And found three signals:

```
    Signals:
void exception(int code, QString source, QString disc, QString help);
void propertyChanged(QString name);
void signal(QString name, int argc, void* argv);
```

I have connected to that signals, but they are not emited neither when Matlab is closed nor when Matlab is ready for next script. Please help me.